# how to compare xpath to current node

Tags: xml, compare, xsl-fo, saxon

I am using saxon to convert xml to xsl-fo. Each file has a companion file that contains xpaths to the elements that have changed. I need to compare the xpath in the companion file against the current node. For example if the current node being processed is item8 then according to the companion file it should get a change bar:

xml file

```
<body>
    <unlist bulltype="NDASH" code="00019292.0001001.007" layer="1" lid="N.00019292.0001001.014">
        <item layer="1">
            <para layer="1" lid="N.00019292.0001001.015">item1</para>
        </item>
        <item layer="1">
            <para layer="1" lid="N.00019292.0001001.018">item2</para>
        </item>
        <item layer="1">
            <para layer="1" lid="N.00019292.0001001.019">item3</para>
        </item>
        <item layer="1">
            <para layer="1" lid="N.00019292.0001001.020">item4</para>
        </item>
        <item layer="1">
            <para layer="1" lid="N.00019292.0001001.021">item5</para>
        </item>
        <item layer="1">
            <para layer="1" lid="N.00019292.0001001.022">item6</para>
        </item>
        <item layer="1">
            <para layer="1" lid="N.00019292.0001001.023">item7</para>
        </item>
        <item layer="1">
            <para layer="1" lid="N.00019292.0001001.024">item8</para>
        </item>
        <item layer="1">
            <para layer="1" lid="N.00019292.0001001.025">item9</para>
        </item>
        <item layer="1">
            <para layer="1" lid="N.00019292.0001001.026">item10</para>
        </item>
    </unlist>
</body>
```

companion file

```
<rev-marks>
    <rev anchor="false" chg="R" origin="airbus"
      path="//*[@lid='N.00019292.0001001.014']/item[9]/para[1]"/>
    <rev anchor="false" chg="R" origin="airbus"
      path="//*[@lid='N.00019292.0001001.014']/item[8]/para[1]">
      <hl-ref ref="hl_1"/>
    </rev>
    <rev anchor="true" chg="R" origin="airbus" path="//*[@lid='N.00019292.0001001.014']"/>
  </rev-marks>
```

Essentially I need to put an fo change bar if the current node's path matches the rev/@path in the companion file. Any help would be appreciated.

*Edited to show what i have so far*

```
<xsl:template match="para">
<!-- path of the current node -->
<xsl:variable name="curPath" select="saxon:path()"/> 
<!-- path of the companion file --> 
<xsl:variable name="mdata">../MU/<xsl:value-of select="ancestor::description/@code"/>_mdata.xml</xsl:variable>
        
<xsl:for-each select="document($mdata,.)//rev">
    <!-- value of //rev/@path in the companion file -->
    <xsl:variable name="revPath" select="@path"/>
                
    <xsl:if test="$revPath = $curPath">
        <fo:change-bar-begin change-bar-class="cbpara" change-bar-color="black" change-bar-style="solid" change-bar-offset="15pt"/>
    </xsl:if>
            
</xsl:for-each>
<fo:block>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</fo:block>
<!-- add fo:change-bar-end here -->
</xsl:template>
```

It is this statement that i cannot get a comparison of the 2 xpath expressions <xsl:if test="$revPath = $curPath">

Hope this clarifies

Comment: Can you edit your post to include whatever xsl you have created so far (or the relevant portion of it)? Do you need help in how to include the companion.xml file? (use <xsl:include />), or in reading the values, or in creating the xpath to perform the matching?

Comment: @Bryn Did this edit help clarify?

Comment: Michael Kay's answer is correct. Do you want to take his first (XSLT3) or second (XSLT1) approach? If you are using xslt3 you can use &ltxsl:evaluate> (see Martin Honnen's answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example of using `xsl:evaluate` (supported in Saxon 9.8 and later of the PE and EE editions, in Saxon 10 all editions and in Saxon-JS 2) is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">
    
    <xsl:param name="rev-doc-uri" as="xs:string">evaluate-key-ref-marks.xml</xsl:param>
    
    <xsl:param name="rev-doc" select="doc($rev-doc-uri)"/>
    
    <xsl:function name="mf:select-node" as="node()*">
        <xsl:param name="path" as="xs:string"/>
        <xsl:param name="context-doc" as="node()"/>
        <xsl:evaluate context-item="$context-doc" xpath="$path"/>
    </xsl:function>
    
    <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="*[some $rev in $rev-doc//rev[@path] satisfies (. is mf:select-node($rev/@path, /))]">
        <xsl:comment>marked</xsl:comment>
        <xsl:next-match/>
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

[Online sample using Saxon-JS 2 in the browser (second XML is inlined there for self-completeness of the example)](https://martin-honnen.github.io/xslt3fiddle/?xslt=%3C%3Fxml%20version%3D%221.0%22%20encoding%3D%22UTF-8%22%3F%3E%0D%0A%3Cxsl%3Astylesheet%20xmlns%3Axsl%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2FXSL%2FTransform%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20xmlns%3Axs%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2001%2FXMLSchema%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20xmlns%3Amf%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fmf%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20exclude-result-prefixes%3D%22%23all%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20version%3D%223.0%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aparam%20name%3D%22rev-doc-uri%22%20as%3D%22xs%3Astring%22%3Eevaluate-key-ref-marks.xml%3C%2Fxsl%3Aparam%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aparam%20name%3D%22rev-doc%22%3E%0D%0A%3Crev-marks%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Crev%20anchor%3D%22false%22%20chg%3D%22R%22%20origin%3D%22airbus%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20path%3D%22%2F%2F*%5B%40lid%3D%27N.00019292.0001001.014%27%5D%2Fitem%5B9%5D%2Fpara%5B1%5D%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Crev%20anchor%3D%22false%22%20chg%3D%22R%22%20origin%3D%22airbus%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20path%3D%22%2F%2F*%5B%40lid%3D%27N.00019292.0001001.014%27%5D%2Fitem%5B8%5D%2Fpara%5B1%5D%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Chl-ref%20ref%3D%22hl_1%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Frev%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Crev%20anchor%3D%22true%22%20chg%3D%22R%22%20origin%3D%22airbus%22%20path%3D%22%2F%2F*%5B%40lid%3D%27N.00019292.0001001.014%27%5D%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Frev-marks%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Aparam%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Afunction%20name%3D%22mf%3Aselect-node%22%20as%3D%22node%28%29*%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aparam%20name%3D%22path%22%20as%3D%22xs%3Astring%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aparam%20name%3D%22context-doc%22%20as%3D%22node%28%29%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aevaluate%20context-item%3D%22%24context-doc%22%20xpath%3D%22%24path%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Afunction%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Amode%20on-no-match%3D%22shallow-copy%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Atemplate%20match%3D%22*%5Bsome%20%24rev%20in%20%24rev-doc%2F%2Frev%5B%40path%5D%20satisfies%20%28.%20is%20mf%3Aselect-node%28%24rev%2F%40path%2C%20%2F%29%29%5D%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Acomment%3Emarked%3C%2Fxsl%3Acomment%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Anext-match%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Atemplate%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%3C%2Fxsl%3Astylesheet%3E&input=%3Cbody%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cunlist%20bulltype%3D%22NDASH%22%20code%3D%2200019292.0001001.007%22%20layer%3D%221%22%20lid%3D%22N.00019292.0001001.014%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Citem%20layer%3D%221%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cpara%20layer%3D%221%22%20lid%3D%22N.00019292.0001001.015%22%3Eitem1%3C%2Fpara%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fitem%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Citem%20layer%3D%221%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cpara%20layer%3D%221%22%20lid%3D%22N.00019292.0001001.018%22%3Eitem2%3C%2Fpara%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fitem%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Citem%20layer%3D%221%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cpara%20layer%3D%221%22%20lid%3D%22N.00019292.0001001.019%22%3Eitem3%3C%2Fpara%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fitem%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Citem%20layer%3D%221%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cpara%20layer%3D%221%22%20lid%3D%22N.00019292.0001001.020%22%3Eitem4%3C%2Fpara%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fitem%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Citem%20layer%3D%221%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cpara%20layer%3D%221%22%20lid%3D%22N.00019292.0001001.021%22%3Eitem5%3C%2Fpara%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fitem%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Citem%20layer%3D%221%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cpara%20layer%3D%221%22%20lid%3D%22N.00019292.0001001.022%22%3Eitem6%3C%2Fpara%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fitem%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Citem%20layer%3D%221%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cpara%20layer%3D%221%22%20lid%3D%22N.00019292.0001001.023%22%3Eitem7%3C%2Fpara%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fitem%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Citem%20layer%3D%221%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cpara%20layer%3D%221%22%20lid%3D%22N.00019292.0001001.024%22%3Eitem8%3C%2Fpara%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fitem%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Citem%20layer%3D%221%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cpara%20layer%3D%221%22%20lid%3D%22N.00019292.0001001.025%22%3Eitem9%3C%2Fpara%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fitem%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Citem%20layer%3D%221%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cpara%20layer%3D%221%22%20lid%3D%22N.00019292.0001001.026%22%3Eitem10%3C%2Fpara%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fitem%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Funlist%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Fbody%3E&input-type=XML).

Comment: How would you handle an ambiguous rev/@path like //item/para? there is a case like this where all item/para should be marked. in your example it only marked item/para[8] and item/para[9]

Comment: @user3618078, I am not sure I remember all the details but I think then you want e.g. `xsl:template match="*[some $rev in $rev-doc//rev[@path] satisfies (. intersect mf:select-nodes($rev/@path, /))]"` where I have simply renamed the existing function to be named `mf:select-nodes`.

Answer (score 2):

There are two general approaches to this.

One is to use `xsl:evaluate` to evaluate the XPath expressions in the companion file. The exact solution depends on the detail of the requirement: for example I'm not sure whether all the `<rev>` elements are treated the same way, or what the significance of the `@anchor` and `@rev` and `@origin` attributes is.

The second way is to write a transformation that converts your companion file to an XSLT stylesheet that does the real work (typically, every `<rev>` element is translated to an `xsl:template` with a match pattern). This sounds a bit daunting, but it's probably the more elegant approach.